# Any ideas how to install old drivers for adaptec's family 5 controllers in xenserver 7?

Tags: xenserver, adaptec

I manage few servers with **Adaptec family 5** controllers.

They are discontinued and no support.

However, is it possible to have storage_manager working on these hosts?

Have anybody succeeded, to install working storage manager on **Xenserver 7**?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, by installing missing dependencies (works in XS 7.1 and 7.2)

Just in case anyone need this, below are commands to execute...

Note:

After reboot **stor_agent.service restart** is required - for now I have not found solution to that, but beside this, your adaptec remote console is fully working and you can fully access your Adaptec controllers.

```
cd /home
wget 
http://download.adaptec.com/raid/storage_manager/asm_linux_x64_v7_31_18856.tgz
tar -xvzf asm_linux_x64_v7_31_18856.tgz 
cd manager/
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libX11-1.6.5-2.fc27.x86_64.rpm
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libX11-common-1.6.5-2.fc27.noarch.rpm
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libxcb-1.12-3.fc26.x86_64.rpm
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libXau-1.0.8-7.fc26.x86_64.rpm
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libXext-1.3.3-5.fc26.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i libX11-common-1.6.5-2.fc27.noarch.rpm
rpm -i libXau-1.0.8-7.fc26.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i libxcb-1.12-3.fc26.x86_64.rpm 
rpm -i libX11-1.6.5-2.fc27.x86_64.rpm 
rpm -i libXext-1.3.3-5.fc26.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i StorMan-7.31.x86_64.rpm
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 34571 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 34572 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 34573 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 34574 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
systemctl enable stor_agent.service
chkconfig --level 2 stor_agent off
```